# Why is Consumption Plan not selectable for me when creating a new Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I'm following the official Microsoft documentation to [create my first Azure Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function). My problem is that I cannot create **a Function App that uses the Consumption Plan** instead of an App Service plan. I only have the option to select one of my **App Service plans**.

Can somebody explain why I do not have the option to choose the **Consumption plan**? It's the option I want to use because I think that this option is best for my project.

That's how it should be:

[image: Hosting Plan option available]

And that's how it looks in my portal:

[image: Hosting Plan option not available]

As you can see the option to choose the **"hosting plan"** is completely missing for me.

Why is that the case and how can I create a Function app that uses the Consumption plan?

Comment: I see you have a German subscription, is this on Azure Germany? Could be related...

Comment: It's not on Azure Germany, thanks for your heads-up. I live in Switerzland, and all my accounts are set to be English. I do not know why this text is in German, to be honest. In short: It's in the "open" Azure cloud.

Comment: OK, strange one then, might be quickest to raise a support ticket, Azure support is very good and you don’t need a support contract necessarily.

Comment: Can you confirm the same behavior in a different browser?

Comment: @AnthonyChu it's the same behavior on all major browsers including Microsoft Edge.

Comment: what does it show you when you click on the "App Service Plan" field?

Comment: also, have you tried using the CLI? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli#create-a-function-app